# Локализация чата русскоязычного сообщества StackOverflow

Tags: предложение, статус-отклонено, локализация, чат

Возможна ли технически и планируется ли локализация [чата](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--)?

Понятно, что чат - это фича, вероятно, в большей степени для постоянных участников сообщества, но тем не менее: будет ли там русскоязычный UI?

Comment: Да если честно вебчат это плохая идея. XMPP или IRC было бы неплохо поднять.

Comment: @igumnov, если в инфраструктуре SO уже есть решение для чатов, вряд ли они станут поднимать сбоку что-то еще.

Comment: Почему-то пропустил ваш вопрос. Добавил вопрос как тему обсуждения для планерки.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky какие результаты?

Answer (score 2):

В общем-то, и раньше не было планов по чату особых. Он, в целом, свою функцию выполняет. По поводу же локализации...

Сейчас уточнил у сотрудников, по чату никаких изменений в обозримом будущем не планируется. В том числе и по части локализации.

Можно, к примеру, юзер скриптами перевести.